# SharePoint Online 2013 with Edge or Chrome Oslo modal layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, oslo

I couldn't figure out how to fix this issue with Edge or Chrome. Rather than display all the fields on a single modal page, it adds a scroll bar when there are plenty of blank space at the bottom.

I have the following css attached to the newifs.aspx (using Oslo layout):

```
<style unselectable="on">
#contentBox {
margin-left:20px!important;
}
#sideNavBox {
width:20px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;
}
</style>
```

The webpart appearance is set to adjust height/width to fit zone.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that SharePoint has an inline style:
    `<div id="s4-workspace" style="width: 758px; height: 450px; overflow-y: auto;">`

So I just added the following in the css to override the height:

```
#s4-workspace { heigh:800px !important; overflow: auto !important}
```

seems to fix the issue.

Comment: You may want to mark your answer as the correct answer if it fixed your problem!

Comment: I tried but I have to wait 2 days. I'll do it then

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that! My bad then.